# Failed to install a ruby gem, eventmachine

Tags: software-installation, ruby, gem

I tried to run a script that return this error messaged:

```
Could not find gem 'eventmachine (= 0.12.10) ruby' in the gems  
available on this machine. Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Results of `sudo bundle install` :

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/......... 
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.. 
Using addressable (2.2.8)  
Using ansi (1.4.3)
Using daemons (1.1.9)
Using data_objects (0.10.10)
Using dm-core (1.2.0)
Using dm-do-adapter (1.2.0)
Using dm-migrations (1.2.0)
Using do_sqlite3 (0.10.10)
Using dm-sqlite-adapter (1.2.0)
Installing eventmachine (0.12.10) with native extensions   
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError:   
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.  

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb  checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes 
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... yes 
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes 
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes 
checking for rb_time_new()... yes 
checking for sys/event.h... no 
checking for epoll_create() in sys/epoll.h... yes 
creating Makefile

make compiling page.cpp 
compiling sigs.cpp 
compiling files.cpp 
compiling emwin.cpp 
compiling cplusplus.cpp 
compiling pipe.cpp 
compiling kb.cpp kb.cpp: 
In member function 'virtual void KeyboardDescriptor::Read()':  
kb.cpp:79:27: warning: ignoring return value of '‘ssize_t read(int, void*, size_t)', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result] compiling rubymain.cpp 
rubymain.cpp: 
In function 'VALUE t_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)': rubymain.cpp:468:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security] 
rubymain.cpp: 
In function 'VALUE t_bind_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)': rubymain.cpp:488:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security] 
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors make: *** [rubymain.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection. 
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out 
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (0.12.10), and Bundler cannot continue. 
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Results of `sudo gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` :

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing eventmachine:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... yes
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for epoll_create() in sys/epoll.h... yes
creating Makefile
make
compiling page.cpp
compiling sigs.cpp
compiling files.cpp
compiling emwin.cpp
compiling cplusplus.cpp
compiling pipe.cpp
compiling kb.cpp
kb.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void KeyboardDescriptor::Read()’:
kb.cpp:79:27: warning: ignoring return value of ‘ssize_t read(int,
void*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
[-Wunused-result]
compiling rubymain.cpp
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE,
VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:468:42: error: format not a string literal and no format
arguments [-Werror=format-security]
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_bind_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE,
VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:488:42: error: format not a string literal and no format
arguments [-Werror=format-security]
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [rubymain.o] Error 1
Gem files will remain installed in
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
```

Results of `ruby -v` :

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

I have already installed libeventmachine-ruby and ruby-eventmachine.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I just went looking and realized I didn't check back with this question. :(

Comment: Are you still looking for the answer?